# How to get value from IEnumerable collection using its Key?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have IEnumerable collection like following

```
IEnumerable<Customer> items = new Customer[] 
{ 
     new Customer { Name = "test1", Id = 999 }, 
     new Customer { Name = "test2", Id = 989 } 
};
```

I want to get value using key `Id`

I tried like following

```
public int GetValue(IEnumerable<T> items,string propertyName)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
      {
           (typeof(T).GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(typeof(T), null));
           // I will pass propertyName as Id and want all Id propperty values 
           // from items collection one by one.
      }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use Select method? It's type safe too.

Comment: `items.Select(x=>x.Id)` would do it. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: If you want to do it in a "generic" way, you can supply a Func<T, bool> selector (predicate) to your method instead of your `propertyName` argument and then use that in the linq where clause. Same with what you need to select. If it's the whole `T` item, you don't need a specific `select` but if you need just a specific property, pass another selector function (of type `Func<T, whatever type>`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> // I will pass propertyName as Id and want all Id propperty values
>
> // from items collection one by one.

If I understand you correctly

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetValues<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string propertyName)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var prop = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
    foreach (var item in items)
        yield return prop.GetValue(item, null);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to retrieve a `Customer` name from a collection by its `Id`:

```
public string GetCustomerName(IEnumerable<Customer> customers, int id)
{
    return customers.First(c => c.Id == id).Name;
}
```

Comment: I don't get `c.Id` i'm getting `c.` Equals,GetHashCode,GetType,ToString

Comment: probably because you query on `IEnumerable<object>` , not `IEnumerable<Customer>`, try something like `customers.OfType<Customer>()`

Comment: @Neo, I think you need to include using System.Linq. It was giving same problem with me, Worked after I included using System.Linq

Comment: @ArvindKrmar you saved the day my freind

Answer (score 14):

Using `LINQ` you can get all customers names (values) having specific value in this way:

```
var valuesList = items.Where(x => x.Something == myVar).Select(v => v.Name).ToList();
```

For single customer name you can do this:

```
var singleName = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1)?.Name;
```

Obviously, the Id can be 1, 2 or any other.

Edit:

I recommend you `List<Customer>` instead of `Customer[]`

So,

```
var items = new List<Customer> 
{ 
     new Customer { Name = "test1", Id = 999 }, 
     new Customer { Name = "test2", Id = 989 } 
};
```

Comment: I don't get `x.Id` i'm getting `x.` Equals,GetHashCode,GetType,ToString

Comment: Use casting as `(Customer)x.Id`.

Comment: @Neo If you will use `List<Customer>` then now need for any casting otherwise casting needed for anonymous type.

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?

Comment: Very helpful advice to include both methods for obtaining either a collection of customers or a single customer. I only add: if anyone is confused on the advice for typing the IEnumerable object as a List, here's one way that could be done if the object already exists as an IEnumerable: 
`var customers = (objectYourIEnumberableCollectionComesFrom.Customers).ToList();`  (basically: just set  a variable equal to the IEnumerable collection then cast to list)

Answer (score 7):

Just use LINQ to achieve what you want to do. if  you want to retrieve a specific value you can use `where` like this:

```
public Customer GetCustomerById(IEnumerable<Customer> items,int key)
{
    return items.Where(x=>x.id==key)
   .Select(x =>x.Name)
   .First(); 
}
```

this will retrieve the customer who match a specific Id.

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to look things up repeatedly after creating the list? If so, you might want to consider creating a dictionary to do the lookups, like so:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> items = new Customer[]
{
    new Customer {Name = "test1", Id = 999},
    new Customer {Name = "test2", Id = 989}
};

var lookup = items.ToDictionary(itemKeySelector => itemKeySelector.Id);

var result = lookup[989];

Console.WriteLine(result.Name); // Prints "test2".
```

I'm assuming that you don't create the collection in the first place - if you had control over creating the original collection you could use a dictionary in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

```
private TextBox [] Collectionstextboxonpanel(Panel panel)
{

    var textBoxspanel1 = panel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>(); // select controls on panle1 by type

    IEnumerable<TextBox> textBoxes = textBoxspanel1; // create collection if need 
    TextBox[] textBoxes1 = textBoxes.ToArray(); // Array collection
    return textBoxes1;                         // get back TextBox Collection
}
```

Comment: Hello Igor! Explain in a sentence or two what you did in the code that would be more understandable.

Comment: @Pluto’s point is always a good practice, but it is _especially_ important on these old questions with established answers. Why take this approach over the other five answers?

Comment: Hi i think it's so simple and no need to be coment, actualy you can away var and type just TextBox [] somename = panel1.Controls.Oftype<TextBox>().Toarray(); this you just make collection of allcontrol items located on panel1 with Type ,TextBox> after all you have constant collection ( meaning index will be same and you can manage this for data write/record)

Comment: the index will be same at all time , after array() , you have constant index. for read or write you don't need to know Textbox Names just create algotimth for take info and write , reading will use the same index.